# With Maven, can I mark a dependency so that versions:display-dependency-updates does not complain about it?

Tags: scala, maven

Most dependencies in my Maven project have suffix _2.11, however, some don't. One example being scala-lang:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since 2.11.8 is the latest 2.11 version, that is the one I want to use, and I don't want to update it until all other dependencies become available in their _2.11 version. The `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` is very practical to find updates, however, for that particular dependency this suggestion is rather worthless:

```
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   org.scala-lang:scala-library ..................... 2.11.8 -> 2.12.0-M4
```

Is there a way to mark a dependency as "this dependency for sure has the version I want, don't complain about it"? Obviously, even if 2.11.9 would come out, it wouldn't be reported anyway, so for this one I'm forever stuck with doing a manual check.

Comment: At the moment not. It might be worth to make a feature request for such things on the project https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues